# Function onReady instead on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working function on button click,
I need to remove the button and run the function as the page loads completely.
Could somebody help me to do that. I am doing this on wix.

```
export function button1755_click(event) {
$w("#ddCabinet").selectedIndex = 15;
$w("#dropdown25").selectedIndex = 0;
$w("#dropdown26").selectedIndex = 1;
$w("#inteldropdown1").selectedIndex = 0;
$w("#ddGraphiccard").selectedIndex = 1;
$w("#ddGraphiccardQty").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: try using **window.onload** in JavaScript. also: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Answer (score 0):

- Using the [`$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) jquery function, you can execute your code when page load:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    // your code here

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is that applicable for wix ???
as i have seen there scripts start from $w??
I m new in programming

Comment: and where should i put my rest codes i mentioned???
as you closed the function

Comment: `$w` is apparently an alias for jQuery on your site. You'd use it instead of just `$`, which is the default alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: Your code would replace the sample console log code, inside the `.ready` function.